# How do I Store application data during a CUIT execution to use later in another test

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm developing a Coded UI test project with Visual Studio 2012 for a WPF application.  Is there a way to query and store a value from a control to use in future test in a test suite.  The  applications creates item ids that I want to use to display the item.

Comment: If you run your tests in one session then use static variables.

Comment: Yes, it will be in the same session.  My question is not very clear.  I don't know how to query the UI to get the value.  I know what I want to do with it once I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.  I was over thinking the issue.
I manually created a wpftext control with the appropriate search criteria and took the text value of the control.  The same way the code generator defines the controls.

```
        private WpfText _LoadNumberText = null;
        public WpfText LoadNumberText
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._LoadNumberText == null))
                {
                    this._LoadNumberText = new WpfText(this.UIGradeStarpoweredbyExWindow.UIItemCustom2.UIItemCustom1);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this._LoadNumberText.SearchProperties[WpfText.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "DocNumber";
                    this._LoadNumberText.WindowTitles.Contains("Window Title");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this._LoadNumberText;
            }
```